Keeping a form centered on mobile in Bulma? (when it's centered on desktop)
I have been imporoving my ancient webdesign skills lately and decided to try out Bulma for a simple todo list flask app. Everything works great but when I reduce the screen size for mobile/tablet, my form and submit button anchor themselves to the left of the screen. Any idea why this is happening? Here's my code...
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="columns is-centered">
                <form action="/update/{{task.id}}" method="POST">
                    <div class="field has-addons">
                        <div class="control">
                          <input class="input" type="text" name="content" id="content" value="{{task.content}}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="control">
                          <button class="button is-info" type="submit" value="Add Task">
                            Submit
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

I tried various other tags for centering the text such as "has-text-centered" as well as adding a column in columns but to no avail. I'd be very greatful if anyone knows why this is happening. I've been quite enjoying so far.
